# How to choose nested object that contains defined property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Object:

```
a = {
    0: {
        name: 'George'
    }
    1: {
        name: 'James'
    }
    smth: {
        notName: '16'
    }
}
```

How to select an object that contains property `name` (0 or 1)? Is it possible to select them like this expression: `a.indexOf('["name"]')`?

Comment: No. But you can iterate over the properties of the outer object and test whether each inner object has that property.

Comment: Lodash can do this easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below returns the list of key that has `name` in the nested object,

```
var list = [];
for (key in a) {
   if (a[key].hasOwnProperty('name')) list.push(key);
}
```

list should contain `["0", "1"]`.